# Retain HTML table styling after exporting to excel using javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, excel

I have a beautiful looking html table from jsfiddle which i will love to convert to excel document. My problem is after creating the excel file. The table loses it styles in excel such as font color, padding, background color. etc. is there a fix for this?

**HTML**

```
<table id="testTable" summary="Code page support in different versions of MS Windows." rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2"><caption>CODE-PAGE SUPPORT IN MICROSOFT WINDOWS</caption><colgroup align="center"></colgroup><colgroup align="left"></colgroup><colgroup span="2" align="center"></colgroup><colgroup span="3" align="center"></colgroup><thead valign="top"><tr><th>Code-Page<br>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>ACP</th><th>OEMCP</th><th>Windows<br>NT 3.1</th><th>Windows<br>NT 3.51</th><th>Windows<br>95</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1200</td><td style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">Unicode (BMP of ISO/IEC-10646)</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>*</td></tr><tr><td>1250</td><td style="font-weight: bold">Windows 3.1 Eastern European</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1251</td><td>Windows 3.1 Cyrillic</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1252</td><td>Windows 3.1 US (ANSI)</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1253</td><td>Windows 3.1 Greek</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1254</td><td>Windows 3.1 Turkish</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1255</td><td>Hebrew</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1256</td><td>Arabic</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1257</td><td>Baltic</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1361</td><td>Korean (Johab)</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>**</td><td>X</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>437</td><td>MS-DOS United States</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>708</td><td>Arabic (ASMO 708)</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>709</td><td>Arabic (ASMO 449+, BCON V4)</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>710</td><td>Arabic (Transparent Arabic)</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>720</td><td>Arabic (Transparent ASMO)</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding : 10px;
}

table
{
    border: 1px solid black;

}
th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;

}
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

input
{
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

[image: BEFORE CONVERTING TO EXCEL]

[image: AFTER CONVERSION]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export Html Table to excel and keep css styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909778/export-html-table-to-excel-and-keep-css-styles)

Comment: the above code for export.. will not work in IE

Comment: can you tell me what is table and name in the function

Answer (score 33):

Finally I figured it out. Using an embedded or external CSS style will not work.

#### Observations

1. CSS must be inline
2. CSS must be on `th` or `td` elements of the table because they represent *cells* in Excel
3. Colors should be hex

#### Summary

From the above code, I don't need an external CSS style. All my CSS styles need to be inline in the table.

Comment: I hate to do inline CSS, but looks like I have to live with it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: once again this answer save me

Comment: I am not able to adjust the column widths in excel to match the width in the html table

Comment: I tried inline css, but it didn't work. Here is my code snippet.


` <tr>
       <th style="border-left: 1px solid #c5c5c5;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;background-color: rgba(197,197,197,0.5) !important;">Normal</th>
       <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;background-color: #fc0 !important">Caution</th>
       <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;background-color: #f90 !important;">Extreme Caution</th>
       <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;background-color: #f00 !important;">Danger</th>
</tr>`

Comment: i to have tried inline styles and opening it up in Excel 2016

Comment: Ankit, you may need to use the full 6 digits of the color. Excel likely does not understand the shorthand eg #FFF vs #FFFFFF

Comment: Colors need not be hex in this condition i had faced, where i did this-$(cell).attr('bgcolor', 'lightgreen');

Comment: @IfeanyiChukwu this eg doesn't working in 2019 do you have another alternative