# export html table to excel with css in angular

Tags: html, excel, angular, typescript

I am trying to export HTML table to excel with applied CSS.I am using [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library for it, but the issue I'm facing is it ain't exporting the table with CSS styles. How do I get it to carry the CSS style, based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909778/export-html-table-to-excel-and-keep-css-styles) I am applying inline CSS to the table elements.

**HTML**

```
  <table #table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Color
    <th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of copy;index as i">
    <td [style.color]="colors[i]">
    {{item}}
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" (click)="fireEvent()">Export</button>
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('table') table: ElementRef;

colors=['Red','Green','Blue','Orange','Violet'];



fireEvent()
{
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(this.table.nativeElement);
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

  /* save to file */
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'SheetJS.xlsx');

}
}
```

I tried using [xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style) library which proclaims to preserve CSS styles and tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467418/retain-html-table-styling-after-exporting-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery) but all in vain.what could be the workaround?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6q9cbw)**

Comment: AFAIK you should use pro version of Sheet.js.

Comment: @Abhi i tried But It did not work either eventually backend team took care of it using Apache-POI if you have found the solution fork my stackblitz and share it  :)

Comment: https://github.com/Krishnakanth94/Xlsx-styles-working-code , Check this

Comment: @Abhi Thanks I will check it out :)

Comment: @Vikas Did that help? I'm looking at the same issue right now so I'm hoping you've got yours working...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Nope I did via Backend

Comment: @Vikas Crap... Apparently, the formatting option is only available in the paid version... However, it might be rather effortless to emulate certain, simple formatting myself. Some work required, sure, but fun project to do.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Well thanks for sharing this, I was unaware of it. Good luck with your project ;)