# How do I format cells in workbook produced by xlsx package under Angular

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, xlsx

*NB. While primarily looking for an answer relating to the xlsx package (as it seems to be vastly suggested and discussed), I fear that it might be impossible. So, I'm also open to going in another direction (as long as it's free and works for Angular/Excel).*

I've found [xlxs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and I'm producing Excel formatted files. I'd like to control a bit of the style so I added the property *s* to a cell as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50087762/1525840) (code sample [here](https://github.com/Krishnakanth94/Xlsx-styles-working-code/blob/master/arraytosheet.html)).

```
testMagic() {
  const table = document.getElementById("donkey");
  const workBook = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table);
  workBook.Sheets.Sheet1.A1.s = { font: { bold: true } };
  XLSX.writeFile(workBook, "wonkey.xlsx");
}
```

I see no difference in the downloaded file, though. I've googled the issue but the combo Angular and xlsx **and** styling isn't commonly blogged.

I'm hoping it's something rather easy to resolve that I'm missing due to confusion and ignorance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are using community(free) version of XLSX package. And the cell styling and other additional features to modify cell formats are only available in Pro version of the library. Please check [here.](http://sheetjs.com/pro)

You can check official information [here.](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx#sheetjs-js-xlsx)

> This is the community version. We also offer a pro version with
>   performance enhancements, **additional features like styling**, and
>   dedicated support.

**P.S.-** An alternative option to update the excel sheet and format the cells, use the [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) npm package. you can see more details about styling [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#styles). 
See the example [here(StackBlitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exceljs-angular-7).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit irrelevant to the question description but makes sense under this question title.

If you are wondering how to format a cell into the category 'text' since your data is automatically changing formats (number to date / phone number to exponential), then there is a parameter that can help while instantiating the Worksheet

`raw:boolean`

Use as:

`const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet=XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tableElement,  {raw:true});`

Comment: is there any way to write in vertical format instead of horizontal?