# How to style cells using XLSX library in angular 6?

Tags: angular, xlsx

I want to add styling in my exported XLSX like alignment. There are ways to do it in XLSX library in angular. But the thing is I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me, please!

Comment: Provide some code or what you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format cells in workbook produced by xlsx package under Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180480/how-do-i-format-cells-in-workbook-produced-by-xlsx-package-under-angular)